# How to handle the error "UNet Client Disconnect Error: Timeout"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

How to handle the error "UNet Client Disconnect Error: Timeout"? How not reboot the application, when it occurs?

Comment: There are probably a thousand possobilities of getting such error, please provide more information, may be some code could help either.

Answer (score 1):

I now resolve this issue.

I think this can help you too.

```
myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Error, OnError);

void OnError(NetworkMessage msg){
    //Error handler code
}
```

This Error client receive with "UNET Client Disconnect Error: Timeout".

My solution: If i not have server. I set current client as Server.